# how to fetch specific collection from mongodb in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have clouded the mongodb collection for my project in Amazon server.

I am new to mongodb queries. When I connect and look in 'robomongo' tool, I can see that there two databases A and B. I want to access the one collection named 'wl_c' under B in view function in django and convert to JSON data.

I do not know how to do even though I tried,

```
from pymongo import Connection
server = '000.00.000.00'
port = 00000
conn = Connection(server,port)

def mongo(request):
  mdb = conn.events.polls_post.find({})
  data = json.dumps(mdb)
  return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/json")
```

got

```
Type error mdb is not json serializable
```

Answer (score 1):

find({}) returns cursor. You need to get the items. Either cast to list or iterate over the result.

Something like:

```
mdb = conn.events.polls_post.find({})
mdb_list = list(mdb)
json.dumps(mdb_list)
```

Look [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#querying-for-more-than-one-document)

Comment: getting an empty list. The collection i want to fetch is a sub item under B. is this method enough to collect it?

Comment: are you using the right DB? Syntax is conn.<db>.<collection>